# The query in HibernateSearch does not sort by updated data

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm using HibernateSearch `5.7.1.Final` with ElasticSearch from Java.
I have two main types of objects in my model,
`Book` and `Journal`, which inherit from class `Record`
and share some common properties: `rank` and `title`.
The typical rank for a book is `1` and typical value for a journal
is `2`, but sometimes it can be different.

I created some data with default rank, but for one book
I wanted to test if updates to the rank value will be respected
in the query results.

I first set it value to `0` before saving:

```
...
Book book03 = new Book("Special Book", prus);
book03.setRank(0);
session.save(book03);
```

Then I obtain the object using Hibernate (not HibernateSearch)
mechanisms, and update the value:

```
session.clear();
session.beginTransaction();
Criteria specialCriteria = session.createCriteria(Book.class);
Book special = (Book) specialCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("title", "Special Book")).uniqueResult();
special.setRank(6);
session.saveOrUpdate(special);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Now I want to obtain all books and journals and sort them by rank.
I combine a query for books and a query for journals using a boolean query.
I don't know how to obtain all objects of a specific type, without including any criteria, so I query
for objects that have anything in a title.

```
session.clear();
sessionFactory.getCache().evictEntityRegions();

FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
fullTextSession.clear();

QueryBuilder bookQueryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Book.class).get();

QueryBuilder journalQueryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Journal.class).get();

QueryBuilder generalQueryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Record.class).get();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query bookLuceneQuery 
    = bookQueryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("title").matching("*").createQuery();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query journalLuceneQuery 
    = journalQueryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("title").matching("*").createQuery();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query combinedLuceneQuery = generalQueryBuilder
    .bool()
        .should( bookLuceneQuery )
        .should( journalLuceneQuery )
    .createQuery();

FullTextQuery combinedQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(combinedLuceneQuery, Record.class);
Sort sort = generalQueryBuilder.sort()
    .byField("rank").asc()
    .createSort();

combinedQuery.setSort(sort);      

List result = combinedQuery.list();

System.out.println("\n\nSearch results for books and journals:");
for(Object object : result)
{
    Record record = (Record) object;
    System.out.println(record.getTitle());
    System.out.println(record.getRank());
    System.out.println();
}
```

The problem is that I obtain the following results:

```
Special Book
6

book01
1

book02
1

book04
1

journal01
2

journal02
2
```

It looks like the value finally updated to `6`
(this value is displayed when *printing* the object),
but during sorting the value `0` is used
(that's why the `Special Book` got to the top).

As you can see I tried resetting the session so that nothing gets cached,
but it didn't help.

My another hypothesis is that the `rank` is not the only element
that affects the sorting, but also some *relevance* is taken into consideration,
because the problem does not occur when I don't use the boolean
query. When I only ask for books, `Special Book` is the last
in the result list. But I would prefer to use the combined query
so that I can paginate the results.

Comment: Given this line `session.saveOrUpdate(special);` Have you checked in Elasticsearch directly to check the value for your `SpecialBook`? If so is it 6 or 0?

Comment: I added *pauses* in the code and dumped ElasticSearch data. After first code fragment execution it is set to 0 and after second it is set to 6 and it stays like this (so it is also 6 during query execution and sorting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Elasticsearch (and Hibernate Search, when it uses Elasticsearch) is *near real-time*, meaning there will be a slight delay (1 second by default) before your updates affect the results of search queries. The moment when updates are taken into account is called a "refresh".

Did you try adding a slight pause (e.g. 2s) after your update?
If it solves the issue, then the refresh delay was causing it. In real-world situation the delay may not be a problem, because you will rarely perform an update and then do a query just after that requires the index to be perfectly up to date.
If you do have such requirements though, you can set the property `hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.refresh_after_write` to `true`. Be aware that this will impact performance negatively, though.